# How to integrate request tracker 4.0.8 with active directory 2008 server

Tags: active-directory, request-tracker

I have installed request tracker v 4.0.8 and everything is working. Now I'm trying to integrate it with Active Directory 2008. I used this DOC: http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/CentOS5InstallPlusSome

But unable to get it working. The RT weblogin doesn't even check for the AD server. I can't find any logs regarding to it. I have already seen a question here in serverfault regarding active directory and Rt, but it was for old version and I'm using a new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. in your apache config place:

```
<Location /rt>
        AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
        SetHandler perl-script
        PerlResponseHandler RT::Mason
        Require valid-user
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "RT Server"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative Off
        AuthLDAPBindDN "domainName\someExistingADUser"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword passwordForThatUser
        AuthLDAPURL ldap://address.of.your.domain.controller:389/ou=Users,dc=some,dc=name,dc=ofyourdomain?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)
</Location>
<LocationMatch "/rt/NoAuth">
        Satisfy Any
        Allow from all
</LocationMatch>
<LocationMatch "/rt//REST/1.0/NoAuth">
        Satisfy Any
        Allow from all
</LocationMatch>
```

and in RT_SiteConfig.pm add:

```
Set($WebExternalAuth , 1);
Set($WebFallbackToInternalAuth , 1);
Set($WebExternalAuto , 1);
```

restart apache and hope for the best :]

Comment: Thank you. But doesn't work. Its giving 500 internal error. And can't find anything in error log.

Comment: try finding out if it's apache giving you 500s or rt - reconfigure things and set ldap-based authentication on some static file or folder not related to rt.

Comment: No. Even RT doesn't send the error. I checked in RT logs too. I don't understand what you mean by setting up static file.

Comment: try to use ldap authentication within apache for a static folder; forget about rt at this stage and try to see if ldap authentication in apache works. if it does not - it's apache configs you need to check; if it does - it's time to look more into details of rt.

Comment: You are right. I made a test file and checked. Its shows the same error 500.

Comment: so you know it's not a problem with RT but with your apache. try enabling more verbose logging, make sure you check all log files. maybe you dont have the mod_ldap.so loaded?

Comment: Finally got working.  Actually, I forgot that I created a separate config for rt and apache check that config for /rt and I updated rt.conf with this code and AD integration works. Thanks a lot "pQd'.