# Active Directory user cache in Request tracker

Tags: active-directory, request-tracker

I have installed Request tracker v 4.0.8 and recently I have integrated it with Active Directory 2008 using the link: [How to integrate request tracker 4.0.8 with active directory 2008 server](https://serverfault.com/questions/462087/how-to-integrate-request-tracker-4-0-8-with-active-directory-2008-server/462090#462090)

and it works. But I have encountered with one strange issue. When I login to the RT using the AD username and pass, it logs in and works fine. But then after I delete that AD user in the AD server, that user is still able to login to the RT until I restart the apache in RT server. I think Apache is caching the AD user. That is why a deleted AD user can still login to the RT server until I restart Apache in RT server. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ldap.conf, did you disable caching?

```
LDAPCacheEntries 0
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ldap.html#ldapcacheentries